# ASP.NET Core form validation fails when trying to save field with foreign key id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having trouble with saving a form which has a foreign key id relation in the model.

The models are as below.

Item model:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace NVFlexo.Models;

[Index(nameof(ItemCode), IsUnique = true)]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Item Code")]
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Item Description")]
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public double Cost { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    [DisplayName("Sale Price")]
    public double SalePrice { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public double Micrones { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public double Density { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("ItemCategory")]
    [DisplayName("Item Category")]
    public int ItemCategoryId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ItemCategory ItemCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Item Category model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace NVFlexo.Models;

[Index(nameof(CategoryName), IsUnique = true)]
public class ItemCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    
    public virtual DbSet<Item> Items { get; }
}
```

Form controller method is as below:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(ItemAndItemCategoriesViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ItemCategory cat = _itemCategoriesService.getById(viewModel.Item.ItemCategory.Id);
            
            Item newItem = new Item();
            newItem.ItemCode = viewModel.Item.ItemCode;
            newItem.ItemDescription = viewModel.Item.ItemDescription;
            newItem.Cost = viewModel.Item.Cost;
            newItem.SalePrice = viewModel.Item.SalePrice;
            newItem.Density = viewModel.Item.Density;
            newItem.Micrones = viewModel.Item.Micrones;
            newItem.ItemCategory = cat;
            _db.Items.Add(newItem);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["success"] = "Item Created Successfully";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        viewModel.ItemCategories = _itemCategoriesService.getAllCategories();
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The part of the view is as below that has the relationship.

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <label asp-for="Item.ItemCategory"></label>
    <select asp-for="Item.ItemCategoryId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.ItemCategories, "Id", "CategoryName"))"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Item.ItemCategory" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Below is the view model.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using NVFlexo.Models;

namespace NVFlexo.ViewModels;

public class ItemAndItemCategoriesViewModel
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ItemCategory> ItemCategories { get; set; }
}
```

I get the below 2 errors but I can confirm that there is a selected value on form submission.

> The ItemCategory field is required.
> The ItemCategories field is required.

Appreciate any help on this.
Newbie to C# and ASP.Net Core.

Comment: What doest `ItemAndItemCategoriesViewModel` look like and which validations does it have?

Comment: I've added the view model. It has no validations @GertArnold

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove the `[Required]` from Navigation Properties as it is not needed with the foreignkey. you do not need to retrieve and assign the `ItemCategory` object in your controller. instead, you could just set the `ItemCategoryId` on the `Item` object.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(ItemAndItemCategoriesViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Items.Add(viewModel.Item); // viewModel.Item should have ItemCategoryId set from the form.
            _db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["success"] = "Item Created Successfully";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        viewModel.ItemCategories = _itemCategoriesService.getAllCategories();
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

view:

```
<select asp-for="Item.ItemCategoryId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.ItemCategories, "Id", "CategoryName"))"></select>
<span asp-validation-for="Item.ItemCategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
```

In `ItemCategory` model, change the definition of the `Items` set to be an `ICollection<Item>` rather than a `DbSet<Item>`, as it describes a collection property rather than a `DbSet.